# Remove coordinates for any NAs in a single dimension - python xarray

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause, python-xarray

I've got a dataset with 3 coordinates, lat, lon and time. In my analysis, there cannot be any missing values along the time axis (For any given pair of lat and lon, all values along the time series should be a number). Therefore I look for a method that removes the pair (lat, lon) from the dataset if there is at least one NA along the time axis (or at least makes the entire series NA).

Example of the dataset follows:

```
Out[107]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'tmp' (time: 4, lat: 3, lon: 6)>
array([[[       nan, 0.05436337, 0.23391456, 0.51244852, 0.42514332,
         0.2335593 ],
        [0.62059169, 0.62898597, 0.5293765 , 0.33062813, 0.30996141,
         0.39869431],
        [0.55619471, 0.68936606, 0.21171338, 0.89683576, 0.16176406,
         0.74822855]],

       [[0.73992303, 0.91800564, 0.24862385, 0.1742356 , 0.22463234,
         0.09875687],
        [0.2319994 , 0.14531623, 0.72293203, 0.4475784 , 0.65764422,
         0.98461684],
        [0.34965378, 0.94495332,        nan, 0.65975544, 0.16506345,
         0.2476436 ]],

       [[0.74008539, 0.70552147, 0.71469424, 0.17502713, 0.60169445,
         0.12387101],
        [0.98992485, 0.35316655, 0.42242635, 0.66903901, 0.63261312,
         0.99028592],
        [0.7503372 , 0.1480758 , 0.46847969, 0.78745792, 0.81341805,
         0.01111322]],

       [[0.57655263, 0.82188197, 0.01296615, 0.46871847, 0.79409789,
         0.86067005],
        [0.5350068 , 0.93970056, 0.2482184 , 0.09425715, 0.04223387,
         0.69450503],
        [0.1050176 , 0.05850025, 0.96669352, 0.2844037 , 0.01956352,
         0.60538931]]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2010-03-31 2010-06-30 2010-09-30 2010-12-31
  * lat      (lat) int32 -60 0 60
  * lon      (lon) int32 -180 -120 -60 0 60 120
```

Code for generating a similar dataset:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset({
    var: xr.DataArray(
        np.random.random((4, 3, 6)),
        dims=['time', 'lat', 'lon'],
        coords=[pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=4, freq='Q'),
            np.arange(-60, 90, 60),
            np.arange(-180, 180, 60)])
    for var in ['tmp']})

ds.tmp[0,0,0] = 0
ds.tmp[1,2,2] = 0

ds = ds.where(ds.tmp > 0)
```

Cheers.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "there cannot be any missing values along the time axis"?

Comment: Sure! If you select any given pair of lat,lon, there will be a 1D array( or series) along time (ex: 2010, 2011, 2012). If in this array there is one or more NAs, I would like to remove the entire array (and therefore the pair of lat, lon) from the dataset. Does it make sense? This is for a ML training where I need continuous data. Thank you!